# Перевод русских символов в двоичный вид

Tags: кодировка, binary

Есть один ресурс (https://decodeit.ru/binary), который переводит обычный текст в двоичный вид и обратно.

Текст с латинскими символами переводит по всем понятной схеме, берёт символ и по аски таблице его переводит в двоичное число.

НО...
На один русский символ приходится сразу два двоичных числа, причем без какой либо заметной закономерности. Пример (скриншоты): https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXdtn.jpg

Кто может объяснить, по какому механизму генерируются двоичные кода для русских символов? Не думаю что там какая-то уникальная авторская система

Comment: https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1024

Comment: `UTF-8` сейчас де-факто современный стандарт, такое надо знать :)

Comment: Двоичным видом можно представить любой код. Ваш похож на UTF-8, но тот же Unicode и win1251 не запрещено делать в двоичном предствавлении.